# How can I get the value of all the same properties in an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, npm, jestjs

So I am doing a npm test on object **books**. I want to get the value of the **title** property from the **books** object. If  I call the function **getTheTitles(books)**, the value of both *'Book'* and *'Book2'* will be returned. I tried writing my code and run npm test but the result shown that there is one undefined in addition to ***Book*** and **Book2**. Is there some changes need to be done on my **getTheTiles** function ?The following are the code :

```
const books = [
    {
      title: 'Book',
      author: 'Name'
    },
    {
      title: 'Book2',
      author: 'Name2'
    }
  ]
```

---

```
let titles = ['title'];

  const getTheTitles = function(item) {
    return titles.map(function(k) {
        return item[k];
    })
 }

getTheTitles(books);
```

------------------ Below are the npm test and it's expected result -----------

```
const getTheTitles = require('./getTheTitles')

describe('getTheTitles', () => {
    const books = [
      {
        title: 'Book',
        author: 'Name'
      },
      {
        title: 'Book2',
        author: 'Name2'
      }
    ]

  test('gets titles', () => {
    expect(getTheTitles(books)).toEqual(['Book','Book2']);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The callback for `map` function is not quite correct.

You can simply do

```js
const data = [{ title: 'Book', author: 'Name' }, { title: 'Book2', author: 'Name2' }];

const getTheTitles = (books) => books.map((book) => book.title);
console.log(getTheTitles(data));
```

Comment: seems like i need to keep on refining my fundamentals and understand for this topic. thanks !

Answer (score 3):

Yes the function needs some tweaking.
Something like this should work:

```
const getTheTitles = bookList => {
    return bookList.map(book => book.title);
}
```

That will give you a list of the titles.

Comment: seems like i need to keep on refining my fundamentals and understand for this topic. thanks !